# Is there any way to connect to ssl enabled mysql on apache mod_dbd?

Tags: mysql, apache

I'm currently using `mod_dbd` (module provided by Apache and manage DB connection)

but I can't find a way to connect to ssl enabled MySQL

I'm using `ap_dbd_open` function to get db handle
(https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/database/mod_dbd.c#L793)

Is there any way to connect to SSL enabled MySQL with `mod_dbd` module?

Comment: Mod_dbd  uses dbparams directive to pass connection parameters to the selected database driver as is. You need to figure out how to connect to mysql via ssl through the mysql driver you instalked and use the same parameters with dbparams

Comment: @Shadow
Thank you for your reply. As you said, I checked the source related to the mysql driver, and It was confirmed that the mysql driver source was created with ssl-related parts excluded.

http://apache.webthing.com/svn/apache/apr/apr_dbd_mysql.c - `dbd_mysql_open`

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using MySQL options files. First, make up a group name and add it to your DBDParams, e.g.

```
DBDParams "host=somehostname dbname=apache user=apache pass=somepassword group=websvr"
```

Then, put a group with the same name in a MySQL options file with a colon-separated list of supported ciphers, like this:

```
[websvr]
ssl-cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

Typically your options file will be  `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.  Check your MySQL or MariaDB C-Connector documentation for where options files are located on your platform.

The example above has a short list of two ciphers, but if you have OpenSSL - you can get a full list of supported ciphers with: `$ openssl ciphers`

If you can connect to your databse interactively with `$ mysql --ssl --host=somehostname`, you can show the supported list of ciphers and the cipher currently being used with `mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'ssl_cipher%';`

One word of caution:  If your server is started as root, but then changes to an unprivileged user ID with the [User Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_unixd.html#user), don't choose the options file `~/.my.cnf` because once the uid is changed your application will not be able to access `/root/.my.cnf`.

Comment: I can confirm that this method works without issues. Thanks